# Establishing an encripted directory connection failed(done - 85.25.213.211:80)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, torsocks, directory, tor-install

it isn't illigal in my country and i have checked time and date, windows defender and firewall is turned off.Using this on pc connected to office wifi. tor log is posted below

```
7/29/2018 2:00:43 AM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/29/2018 2:00:43 AM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/29/2018 2:00:43 AM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/29/2018 2:00:43 AM.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/29/2018 2:00:43 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
7/29/2018 2:00:44 AM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
7/29/2018 2:00:55 AM.700 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host CE47F0356D86CF0A1A2008D97623216D560FB0A8 at 85.25.213.211:80) 
7/29/2018 2:00:55 AM.700 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
7/29/2018 2:00:55 AM.700 [WARN]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
7/29/2018 2:00:55 AM.700 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
7/29/2018 2:00:55 AM.700 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/29/2018 2:00:55 AM.700 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/29/2018 2:00:55 AM.700 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/29/2018 2:00:55 AM.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove, comment out or set to 0 the DisableNetwork line in your torrc config file.

DisableNetwork 0|1

When this option is set, we don’t listen for or accept any connections other than controller connections, and we close (and don’t reattempt) any outbound connections. Controllers sometimes use this option to avoid using the network until Tor is fully configured. (Default: 0)